# How to prevent second operation on context in this case?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have code like this:

It has to load data from db with "custom" predicate in `Where`

which has to ask db about permissions to determine true/false

```
public List<User> getUsersWhoCanDoSomething()
{
    return _context
            .Users
            .Where(x => CanPerformAction(user))
            .Take(10000)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate)
            .ToList();
}
```

---

```
private bool CanPerformAction(User user)
{
    var permission = _context
    .Permissions
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == user.Permissions.Name)
    .Level;

    return permission > 5;
}
```

How can I change this code to prevent this exception:

`A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed.`

Comment: Please, edit your question and post the code for the User and Permission model classes, as this might help in providing an answer

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Move `Where`/`Filter` out of the LINQ Chain

```
public List<User> getUsersWhoCan...()
{
    var users = _context
            .Users
            .Include(x => x.Permissions)
            .Take(10000)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate)
            .ToList();

    var tempList = new List<User>();

    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        if (CanPerformAction(user))
        {
            tempList.Add(user);
        }
    }

    return tempList;
}
```

Comment: Note that this asks the db for more data than you want to use. You can combine the filter into a single query to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that you can only use a `DbContext` object for one query at a time. But `CanPerformAction` is executing it's own db call (because of the `FirstOrDefault`) during the time that `getUsersWhoCanDoSomething` is. That's why you're getting the exception.

Your answer will work, but you're asking for more data than you want, then discarding some. If you have more than 10,000 users, then you may be missing some users because of that (because of the `Take(10000)`).

This should do the same thing (I think - I don't know your exact db schema). It combines the condition into the query so you are only getting the data you want.

```
return _context
        .Users
        .Where(u => u.Permissions.Any(l => l.Level > 5))
        .Take(10000)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate)
        .ToList();
```

Another way to do the same thing is to still use your separate method (anything after the `=>` is technically a separate method anyway), but don't reference `_context` or `FirstOrDefault` (which triggers a separate db call). This would do exactly the same thing as my code above, if you use `.Where(x => CanPerformAction(user))`.

```
private bool CanPerformAction(User user)
{
    return user.Permissions.Any(l => l.Level > 5);
}
```

Comment: You're right, but the thing is, that the "real" ``CanPerformAction`` method is way more complex and I have to extract it to other method to make it somewhat readable

Comment: More complex than the `CanPerformAction` method that you posted? Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like it's just checking the user has a permission record with level > 5. No?

Comment: Here yea, but I cannot post the real code. The thing is that I have to ask db for data for a few tables just to determine whether user can perform some action and it'd want to extract it to other method to make it somewhat readable

Comment: I see. I'm sure there is a way to combine it all into the same query. As long as the other tables have relationships with the Users table, then it shouldn't be too hard. I added an example to show how you can keep the conditions in a separate method, which is very similar.